# Custom Android/Flutter versions for specific API levels

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, backwards-compatibility, android-api-levels

I have a Flutter app that's on Google Play and I'm about to add a new feature that requires adding a package that supports only 21+ API Levels. I still want to support API levels below 21 by adding a custom version of my app for them that doesn't have that feature in it on Google Play. Is that's possible? Or is there any other solution?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should use flavors (build variants):

```
flutter create flavorsexample
```

please check below for more details:

https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/flavors

https://cogitas.net/creating-flavors-of-a-flutter-app/

Comment: That very nice but this didn't mention anything about a separate pubspec.yaml for each flavor. Because as you can see, the packages in pubspec.yaml are the main problem. Surely when trying to launch the lower API Level flavor, it will cause build failures.